# Draw svg element ontop of a nested element

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Using either d3.js or a javascript method, is there a way to draw the nested circle (#snap-points) on top of the line group?

```
<g id='panel-group'>
   <rect id='panel-rectangles' />
   <circle id='snap-points' />
</g>

<g id='line-group>
   <line/>
</g>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document.getElementById('snap-points').appendChild(document.getElementById('line-group'))

Should do it i.e. reparent the snap-points element as a child of the line-group.

Comment: Will this affect positioning of the line-group element?

Comment: Maybe, if you've transforms on the panel-group or the line-group.

Comment: I should have been more specific with my question, as both of the elements do have transforms on them.

Comment: Your [mcve] has no transforms. Perhaps you should ask a new question with more representative test case.